# synchronizing on Collections.synchronizedmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable, synchronized

In Collections javadoc it is mentioned like below..

It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
      ...
  Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
      ...
  synchronized (m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
      Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

My Question is, if I declared an Hashtable and can I use it without synchronizing on it. 
Like below

```
  Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
     Set s = m.keySet();

 Iterator i = s.iterator();
          while (i.hasNext())
              foo(i.next());
```

Comment: `Hashtable` is not a synchronized map. Use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's a Map, and it's synchronized. How is it not a synchronized map?

Comment: Where are you using `ht`?

Comment: I don't think you understand the fundamentally different points of thread safety and consistency. Of course you _can_ loop unsynchronized, and you can do the same with an synchronized `HashMap`. But the resulting output will only be weakly consistent with what's in the `Map`. A `ConcurrentHashMap` makes no difference.

Comment: It depends on whether it can be modified by other threads or not.

Comment: I checked myself through the code of Hashtable, it maintains modCount, which notes the modifications count. If two separate threads initiate a iterator and one removes an element, the other thread will throw concurrentModification Exception, which is mentioned in answers below. So we have to synchronize above code if we are using that in multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

[From the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are *fail-fast*: if the Hashtable is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

So, if you want to go through an iterator from a `Hashtable`, you have to ensure that nobody else modifies the `Hashtable` object in the meanwhile. If that object is shared among multiple threads, the best way to do that is to synchronize on a common object, such as that very same `Hashtable` you're iterating over.

Answer (score 3):

> if I declared an Hashtable and can I use it without synchronizing on it.

You can but you shouldn't if you want to avoid a ConcurrentModificationException.  I.e. it uses synchronization just like a synchronized HashMap as has the same limitation.

Note: if you use a ConcurrentHashMap, you don't need to lock it (and in fact you can't)

Answer (score 1):

> if I declared an Hashtable and can I use it without synchronizing on it?

No, you need to synchronize it.

Reason:

- Iteration over [any] collections in Java is not thread safe.
- This is the implementation of the Hashtable#keyset() method:

  `public Set<K> keySet() {
       if (keySet == null)
           keySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new KeySet(), this);
       return keySet;
   }`

  If you notice, it returns synchronizedSet. As it's mentioned in the javadoc `It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned set when iterating over it` because the `iterator` method in the SyncronizedSet is not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing every operation in a single thread, there should be no concurrency issue observed in this case. Though I must say that the example you provided from JavaDoc is not related to example you have question regarding. Please modify the question with more details.